# how to pass checkbox value from jsp to java class

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-security

I have in my jsp page some checkbox and I want to pass in my spring controller the checked ones.

**insertTaskInformation.jsp**

```
<body>
    <div align="center">


        <strong> <strong>Title:</strong>${task.title} <form:form
                action="addSymbol" method="post" name="catch">

                <c:forEach var="symbol" items="${symbols}">
                <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="${symbol.type} }">${symbol.type}<BR>
                </c:forEach>

                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form:form>



        </strong>
</div>

</body>
```

**taksController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addSymbol", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addSymbol() {



        return "administration/taskRecap";


    }
```

Comment: Something tells me that you are going to need to use some workaround here. I don't know Spring but you can always use javascript to create the form response to only add the checked boxes. Juste need to use a simple input (not a submit type) to use your own method of generation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use sp`spring:form` library and you add in your controller something like this :

```
   @PostMapping("/greeting")
public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting) {
    return "result";
}
```

And In  your first controller, you add an attribute to the model with `model.addAttribute(new greeting() )` so the full code will be

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addSymbol", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addSymbol(Model model) {

  model.addAttribute(new greeting() )

    return "administration/taskRecap";


}
```

For more information  check [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/)

Comment: yes I think this, but I have a different problem. I must pass checkbox value into my controller

Comment: Yeah that's why @ModelAttribute is in the controller, that's your attribute.

Comment: yes but checked is a value of the checkbox in the jsp page not an attribute of my object

Comment: I know how to pass model Attribute but in this case I don't want to pass the whole list, but only the values with the chekbox checked